# where is this mystery number coming from in my pascal's triangle program?

Tags: python, recursion, pascals-triangle

I wrote a number to output the nth row of Pascal's Triangle:

```
import sys
def nth_row_pascal(n):

    def nth_num(i, j):

        if i==0:
            print("({},{}) determined to be 1".format(i,j))
            return 1
        if (j == 0) or (j==i):
            print("({},{}) determined to be 1".format(i,j))            
            return 1
        print("calculating pascal number: ({},{})".format(i,j))                
        result=nth_num(i-1, j-1) + nth_num(i-1, j)
        print("answer: " + str(result))
        return result

    result = [nth_num(i, int(n)-1) for i in range(int(n))]
    return result

print(nth_row_pascal(sys.argv[1]))
```

When I run

```
python pascal.py 4
```

I get:

```
python3 pascal.py 4
(0,3) determined to be 1
calculating pascal number: (1,3)
(0,2) determined to be 1
(0,3) determined to be 1
answer: 2
calculating pascal number: (2,3)
calculating pascal number: (1,2)
(0,1) determined to be 1
(0,2) determined to be 1
answer: 2
calculating pascal number: (1,3)
(0,2) determined to be 1
(0,3) determined to be 1
answer: 2
answer: 4
(3,3) determined to be 1
[1, 2, 4, 1]
```

Why is

`answer: 4` popping up?

It seems that the function `nth_num` will print out a statement -- either

1. `i,j determined to be 1`
   or
2. `calculating pascal number` ...

But in this case it goes
`answer: 2`  (understandable)
`answer: 4` (what??)

each time it is executed.

Comment: Display (i,j) and the result at each step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of stuff happens in between the "calculating" and "answer" lines, including other recursive calls!  Here's some ASCII art and some extra whitespace to help clear up where exactly that `answer: 4` comes from:

```
(0,3) determined to be 1

calculating pascal number: (1,3)  >-----\
(0,2) determined to be 1                |
(0,3) determined to be 1                |
answer: 2   <---------------------------/

calculating pascal number: (2,3)  >-----\
                                        |
calculating pascal number: (1,2)  >-\   |
(0,1) determined to be 1            |   |
(0,2) determined to be 1            |   |
answer: 2   <-----------------------/   |
                                        |
calculating pascal number: (1,3)  >-\   |
(0,2) determined to be 1            |   |
(0,3) determined to be 1            |   |
answer: 2   <-----------------------/   |
                                        |
answer: 4   <---------------------------/

(3,3) determined to be 1
```

When tracing recursive functions to understand how they work it can help to print out the depth of the recursive call, like this:

```
from typing import List


def nth_row_pascal(arg: str) -> List[int]:
    n = int(arg)

    def nth_num(i: int, j: int, depth: int) -> int:
        indent = "  " * depth  # for pretty-printing
        if i == 0:
            print(f"{indent}{(i, j)} determined to be 1")
            return 1
        if j in {0, i}:
            print(f"{indent}{(i, j)} determined to be 1")
            return 1
        print(f"{indent}calculating pascal number: {(i, j)}")
        result = nth_num(i-1, j-1, depth+1) + nth_num(i-1, j, depth+1)
        print(f"{indent}answer: {result}")
        return result

    result = [nth_num(i, n-1, 0) for i in range(n)]
    return result
```

```
(0, 3) determined to be 1
calculating pascal number: (1, 3)
  (0, 2) determined to be 1
  (0, 3) determined to be 1
answer: 2
calculating pascal number: (2, 3)
  calculating pascal number: (1, 2)
    (0, 1) determined to be 1
    (0, 2) determined to be 1
  answer: 2
  calculating pascal number: (1, 3)
    (0, 2) determined to be 1
    (0, 3) determined to be 1
  answer: 2
answer: 4
(3, 3) determined to be 1
[1, 2, 4, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about printing out the depth.  Very useful.